# How to place <aside> block underneath <article> block rather than next to it

Tags: html, css

I want to place `<aside>` sidebar column underneath the `<article>` main column(rather than next to it) to suit smaller screens (mobile devices).

How to achieve it in my two-columned website Home Page?

On desktop screen, current side by side display is fine. Only on smaller screen aside block is not coming underneath article block.

```
#main {
    width: 58%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    float: left;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 34%;
    margin-left: 4%;`
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What is the **screen size** you want the **sidebar** to be underneath the main column?

Comment: I do not know the screen size. Just any mobile device screen size, I guess.

Comment: I already updated my answer. Please do check it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ' in #sidebar

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/60t5bf0y/)

```
    #sidebar {
   width: 34%;
   margin-left: 4%;
   float: left;
    }
```

Comment: remove what in #sidebar?

Comment: remove ` symbol.  that is in end of  margin-left: 4%;`

Comment: the symbol you mentioned is already removed but still when you resize the screen to small screen, both main and sidebar still appear next to each other. Only on smaller screen, not desktop screen, how to get sidebar column underneath main column?

Comment: remove clear:both;  @media (max-width: 500px)
#sidebar {
  margin-left: 2%;
}   https://jsfiddle.net/60t5bf0y/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@media` and `width: 100%;`:

**Here's the [JsFiddle link demo](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/60t5bf0y/11/).**

**E.g.** small screen size: 767px

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
     #sidebar,
     #main {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works but the problem is it leaves a blank column space (no content any more; just blank column in its place) on the right hand side as screen becomes smaller. How to get rid of this blank column?

Comment: Do you want to use the entire **row** to be filled with the **main content**?

Comment: Tell me if that's what you want to achieve so that I will be able to update my answer.

Comment: Yes, entire Main content column on smaller screens.

Comment: @sjhawar Done. Already updated my answer. Just use 'width: 100%;'  instead of 'clear: both;'.

Comment: At screen size 767, I see that menu bar collapses on smaller screen so along with it the sidebar column should also collapse.

Comment: You can change the **max-width** value to what ever you want. The code I provided was just a sample **small screen size**.

Comment: Should I give you my website URL for fixing?

Comment: No problem with the code you gave. Thanks a lot. Because I am so new to css, you might notice some problem at srjtax.com (when using the menu bar and clicking on any menu  item, it expands beyond its original size for a second and then shrinks to its original size) while you test resizing on smaller screen to determine the right screen size for the break point.

Comment: I think I can help you with that. I love **css** so that will be easy. Can you provide the code?

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. I use these css files: style.css, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css, and styleslide.css, which you can download from http://www.mediafire.com/download/d19365fw2ku0zq6/css.zip

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I just downloaded the codes. I'm checking it now.

Comment: Can you provide the images and the html files?

Comment: Ok. I suggest that you always put the **style.css** next to **bootstrap.css** in your header. If you will not do that. It will be difficult for you to override the bootstrap default styles.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have revised all files (now collapsible menu on smaller screens; the problem of menu items expanding beyond original size still persists). Please download from: http://www.mediafire.com/download/3rcaa4s197byb7s/Alberto.zip

Comment: Do you mean first put bootstrap.css and then on next line put style.css to override bootstrap.css values? Sorry, I did not do it as I am new to css. Will appreciate your corrections to my files. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right but that's okay. I also encountered that problem when I was a newbie to css. I will try to check your when I got time. Right now I'm kind of busy because I currently developing a web app where I was the front-end developer and some at back-end.

Comment: How are you? Your CSS placement suggestion was helpful. Now I have solved the menu display problem. Take a look at srjtax.com. In Contact  page, I find a problem of proper display (alignment and position) if you can fix it.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. About the contact page of your site, are you referring with the map?

Comment: No, not map. Please try to test contact form by not filling out a required field.  You will find unnecessary blank space before the display line. When successful, the display on top is good but the contact form is not reset (fields still show prior data). Perhaps, the look (such as margin, padding, centering) of display can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  #main, #sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
}
```